# Material Design for XAML Toolkit project setup problem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have started a blank, new .NET framework 4.8.0 WPF project, and am trying to add Material Design for XAML Toolkit into it. I started by following the [quick start guide](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Getting-Started) located on the Github wiki. I installed the nuget packages manually, by using the .nupkg files located [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/releases/tag/v4.3.0). I get to the first second step of adding the libraries, boom, error.

**Could not load file or assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."**

I have looked for hours on how to solve this issue to no avail. Any ideas?

My app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Launcher.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Launcher"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Everything else is as-is since starting the new project.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this from the tutorial works.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

The first two dictionaries produce errors, but still compile and the errors go away after compilation. I have no clue why.